# Facebook application stopped working all of a sudden ; White page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

My Facebook application has stopped working all of a sudden, it just shows a white page. There hasn't been any code change. I tried debugging myself, and it seems like there is an issue with the following line of code.

```
$user_id = $facebook->require_login();
```

Can anyone help me? How I can get started?

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors from that or any other line in your code?

Comment: No, no errors are shown on the page...

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `require_login()` anymore, I believe that you just use something like:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) {
    try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        //  Do something with this error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as you can see I am having the same problem below... it turns out that the solution is to update the authentication method and get the new SDK. See:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

Comment: Thanks I'll try this and let you know

Comment: What are the steps involved in upgrading the SDK.